# Laravel Passing Variables to Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a post route set up like this:

```
Route::post('/product/dashboard', function()
    {
        $from = Input::get('from');
        $to = Input::get('to');

    });
```

And now I would like to pass those to a controller.

I call controllers like this normally:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

How would I go on to that with variables?

Comment: so basically, after submit you redirect to the homepage and want to pass the variables without saving it to the database? then you can do it with [sessions](http://four.laravel.com/docs/session#session-usage) or [flash variables](http://four.laravel.com/docs/session#flash-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not access the Input variables from within the controller?

```
Route::post('product/dashboard', 'HomeController@showDashboard');
```

and in the controller...

```
function showDashboard() {
   $from = Input::get('from');
   $to = Input::get('to');

   // do more stuff
}
```